# detached entity passed to persist error while using @ManyToOne association

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have `Book` & `Bookdetail` class

When I am trying to use same `BookDetail` information for my two `Book` objects using `@ManyToOne`, I am getting

> "detached entity passed to persist error".

I tried same with `JpaRepository` and `CrudRepository`. But same result

Please help me. Thanks in advance

**Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloJpaApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

        Book book1=new Book();
        book1.setName("my thoughts");

        Book book2=new Book();
        book2.setName("your thoughts");

        Bookdetail detail=new Bookdetail();
        detail.setCategory("good books");

        book1.setBookdetail(detail);
        book2.setBookdetail(detail);

        bookRepository.save(book1); 
        bookRepository.save(book2); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloJpaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**BookRepository interface**

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Integer>{

}
```

**Book class**

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int bookid;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Bookdetail bookdetail;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String name) {
    this.name=name;
    }

    public int getBookid() {
        return bookid;
    }
    public void setBookid(int bookid) {
        this.bookid = bookid;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Bookdetail getBookdetail() {
        return bookdetail;
    }
    public void setBookdetail(Bookdetail bookdetail) {
        this.bookdetail = bookdetail;
    }

}
```

**Bookdetail Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bookdetail")
public class Bookdetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int bookid;

    private String category;

    public Bookdetail() {
    }
    public Bookdetail(String category) {
        this.category=category;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every object created just with `Bookdetail detail=new Bookdetail();`  is a detached entity which mean he's not in the hibernate session or don't have a identifier `id`.
And you have to wrap your services which persist or update or delete into a **transaction**.

So first you must save `detail` your detached entity : `bookdetailRepository.save(detail)` to attached it to the session **But** in your case you already specify `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}`

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
private Bookdetail bookdetail;
```

No need to save it before, the job will be done automatically.

the solution then is to annotate the method `run()` with `@Transactional`

```
...
@Transactional
public void run(String... arg0)
    ...
    bookdetailRepository.save(detail)
    book1.setBookdetail(detail);
    ...
```

Comment: Those changes did't resolved the issue... I have posted my changes in the question section itself

Comment: in your gitub project you didn't specify `@EnableTransactionManagement` have you ?

Comment: @jaison also add `@Transactional` before `public void run()`

Comment: Thank you very much Youssef.. I will post the answer as whole for others... once again thank you for your efforts

Comment: your are welcome @jaison ;) i update my answer in case you wanna accept it.

Comment: youssef, It worked for me,, even without bookdetailRepository.save(detail)... I think,  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)....private Bookdetail bookdetail; did that work

Comment: @jaison yeah of course i was editing the answer to put more details :) if something is missing tell me

Comment: @jaison i put `bookdetailRepository.save(detail)` because the others can not specify `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}` in their entities.

Answer (score 1):

@Transactional before public void run() worked for me... Thank you very much @Youssef  and @Chathuranga Tennakoon  for your efforts. Sharing the code for others.

```
@SpringBootApplication
// @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.jpa.repository"})

public class HelloJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloJpaApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    // @Autowired
    // private BookDetailRepository bookDetailRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

        Book book1 = new Book();
        book1.setName("my thoughts");

        Book book2 = new Book();
        book2.setName("your thoughts");

        Bookdetail detail = new Bookdetail();
        detail.setCategory("good books");
        // bookDetailRepository.save(detail);

        book1.setBookdetail(detail);
        book2.setBookdetail(detail);

        bookRepository.save(book1);
        bookRepository.save(book2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloJpaApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int bookid;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Bookdetail bookdetail;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBookid() {
        return bookid;
    }

    public void setBookid(int bookid) {
        this.bookid = bookid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Bookdetail getBookdetail() {
        return bookdetail;
    }

    public void setBookdetail(Bookdetail bookdetail) {
        this.bookdetail = bookdetail;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "bookdetail")
public class Bookdetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int bookid;

    private String category;

    public Bookdetail() {
    }

    public Bookdetail(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

}


@Repository 
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Integer>{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add BookdetailRepository as follows.

```
@Repository
public interface BookdetailRepository extends JpaRepository<Bookdetail,Integer> {

}
```

And change the HelloJpaApplication as follows.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.jpa"}) 
public class HelloJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloJpaApplication.class);

@Autowired
private BookRepository bookRepository;

@Autowired
BookdetailRepository bookdetailRepository;

public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

    Book book1=new Book();
    book1.setName("my thoughts");

    Book book2=new Book();
    book2.setName("your thoughts");

    Bookdetail detail=new Bookdetail();
    detail.setCategory("good books");
    bookdetailRepository.save(detail); //saving the bookDetail

    book1.setBookdetail(detail);
    book2.setBookdetail(detail);

    bookRepository.save(book1); 
    bookRepository.save(book2); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HelloJpaApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: Those changes did't resolved the issue... I have posted my changes in the question section itself

Comment: have you tried     bookdetailRepository.save(detail); //saving the bookDetail ? i have created a project and tested the code i have given. worked for me

Comment: Yes I have tried the same... I am sorry If I did any mistake... I have shared the project in github also.... https://github.com/jaisonsteephen/ManyToOne.git

Comment: try again with  removing @EnableTransactionManagement and changing @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.jpa"})  to @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.jpa.repository"})

Comment: I tried that too.. still no luck.... I posted changes in github...I am running the application with following command:  mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: Adding @Transactional before public void run()   did the trick for me. once again thank you for your efforts